# JavaScript split with regex returning array with empty. Manual removal or regex removal?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've used .split() dozens of times to convert strings into arrays. This is the first time I have received an unexpected result. Here, split returns an array with empty strings. This is odd, as there are no spaces in the string being split.

Is there a regex way to avoid this new and unexpected result, or need I simply remove them with a new line of code?

```
let infix = "(A+B)*C";

let infixArr = infix.split(/(\W)/g);
console.log(infixArr);

Yields -- > [ '', '(', 'A', '+', 'B', ')', '', '*', 'C' ]
Expected --> [ '(', 'A', '+', 'B', ')', '*', 'C' ]
```

Comment: The empty strings are between 2 separators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex - documentation on empty strings before and after characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131980/regex-documentation-on-empty-strings-before-and-after-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are multiple separators next to each other so the string between them is empty. You could filter the empty strings using `filter`:

```
"(A+B)*C".split(/(\W)/g).filter(c => c !== ''); 
//=> ["(", "A", "+", "B", ")", "*", "C"]
```

Comment: Works beautifully without the + in \W+  I was unaware of this behaviour. Thanks for the clarification and response.

Comment: Yeah I accidentally pasted it with a + because I was testing with that :D

Answer (score 2):

With `split` method, you will have empty strings when the string starts with or ends with the separator or there's nothing between two separators as commented @mdatsev. You can use [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with regex `\W|\w+` to extract the patterns you need:

```js
let infix = "(A+B)*C";

console.log(
  infix.match(/\W|\w+/g)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The empty strings are appearing because `\W` is splitting on any non-word character, which includes the parentheses: the first is separating an empty string and A. The second is next to another non-word character, the `*`, hence the second empty string, for the empty space between them.

The non-word characters are then being spliced back into the result array, per the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing
>   parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results
>   (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are
>   spliced into the output array. However, not all browsers support this
>   capability.

If you just want to split into its constituent characters, why not just call `infix.split('')`, out of interest?

Comment: Or `Array.from(infix)` or `[...infix]`. You actually get better support of astrals this way. Split will separate low and high surrogates.

Comment: Your result works fine for this example. More complex examples are ahead for which the regex is best suited.